# Check color CSS file... change colors jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to check with JavaScript (jQuery) if there is a certain CSS file? And if there is that it loads a color array for jQuery plot?

Example:

- I include a color CSS file (blue.css).
- Javascript will check if there is a color CSS file (blue.css, red.css, grey.css).
- There is blue.css in the page and the array colors for that CSS file ... is load for jQuery plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following approach.

1. have a hidden `<div id="colorIndicator" style="display:none"></div>`
2. have a css rule in every **color.css** with a corresponding color `#colorIndicator { color: #ff0000; }`
3. On load make an ajax call to the server and get your colors

This could be the JavaScript using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax( {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/give/me/colors',
      data: { color: $('#colorIndicator').css('color'); },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
         // handle your json data
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like this q/a will help:

[HOW TO check if an external (cross-domain) CSS file is loaded using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794128/how-to-check-if-an-external-css-file-is-loaded-using-javascript)